# Navbar to follow wherever I scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set my navbar to be on top whenever I scroll, but when i use position: fixed; the navbar disappears. Here's my html and css respectively.

```
<nav>
<div class="navbar">
<button class="btn button"> Home <A href="#">   </button>
<button class="btn button"> About Me </button>
<button class="btn button"> Portfolio</button>
<button class="btn button"> Contact Me           </button>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="background-img">

</div>

<div class="portfolio">

<img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP5v6bzfDWAhXEto8KHc_gBDoQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomequity.us%2Fdesignhouse%2Fbungalow_house_design_malaysia.html&psig=AOvVaw3hVzFHYi5ropXAhSrn1oIx&ust=1508087256948636">


</div>
```

The CSS

```
 nav{
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
 }

.btn{
    background-color: Black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 193px 10px 0px;

}

.background-img {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497215842964-222b430dc094?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=2100&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative; 
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define it's fixed position as `top:0`.

```
 nav{
      background-color: transparent;
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      width:100%;
      z-index:15;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) value. And one more thing you probably forget to close the a tag in nav section.

```css
 nav{
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     z-index:99999; /* add z-index value maximum */
 }

.btn{
    background-color: Black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 193px 10px 0px;

}

.background-img {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497215842964-222b430dc094?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=2100&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class="navbar">
<button class="btn button"> <a href="#">Home</a> </button><!-- You need to close the a tag -->
<button class="btn button"> About Me </button>
<button class="btn button"> Portfolio</button>
<button class="btn button"> Contact Me  </button>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="background-img">

</div>

<div class="portfolio">

<img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP5v6bzfDWAhXEto8KHc_gBDoQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomequity.us%2Fdesignhouse%2Fbungalow_house_design_malaysia.html&psig=AOvVaw3hVzFHYi5ropXAhSrn1oIx&ust=1508087256948636">


</div>
```